# Using Undefined Functions in C++

Tags: c++, function

How do I use an undefined function2 in my C++ program? The function2 is defined later, but I need to use the function2 in function1. However, function2 needs function1 to work, too! How do I do this?

```
function1(){...function2()...}
function2(){...function1()...}
```

Something like that.

Comment: I assume you mean _undefined_ function. You **cannot** use an undeclared function because the compiler won't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @The Alien: Well, *declare* it. It is not possible to use undeclared functions in C++.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake! I'm still a noob, so I don't know how to declare it, @AnT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a forward declaration:

```
void function2();
```

This specifies the interface of `function2` (no return value, no parameters) so that `function1` can call it.

Comment: Thank you! So does this mean that if I want to use function2() as a integer value, I can use: `int function2();`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Forward declare both functions.

```
void function1();
void function2();

function1(){...function2()...}
function2(){...function1()...}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have functions calling each other, it's best to declare all the functions first. Then, the functions can be used in the implementation without any problem.

```
// Declarations
void function1();
void fucntion2();

// Implementations
void function1() { ... function2(); }

void function2() { ... function1(); }
```